# How to combine negative lookbehind and negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

## Combine negative lookbehind and negative lookahead

How can I combine **negative lookbehind** `(?<!)` and **negative lookahead** `(?!)` with an **AND**?

With .Net/C#

I want to find the word `big`, but only if it is not inside `(`or `[` or `` ` `` AND `)` or `]` or `` ` ``
The problem is that I can't find `big` either when one of the brackets is there

### Demo

https://regex101.com/r/V78jxd/2

### Regex

`` (?<![\(\[`])big(?!.*[\)\]`]) ``

### Test Data

```
Should Match: 
I like `xx` big `xx` cakes

I like big cakes
I like `big cakes
I like big` cakes
I like xx big xx cakes
I like ` xx big xx cakes
I like xx big xx` cakes
I like `xx` big `xx` cakes

I like big cakes
I like [big cakes
I like big] cakes
I like xx big xx cakes
I like [ xx big xx cakes
I like xx big xx] cakes
I like [xx] big [xx] cakes

I like big cakes
I like (big cakes
I like big) cakes
I like xx big xx cakes
I like ( xx big xx cakes
I like xx big xx) cakes
I like (xx) big (xx) cakes
                                               
I like (xx(test(big test big ( big ))) big xx) big  (xx(test(big test big ( big ))) big xx) cakes
                                               ^^^

Should not Match: 
I like (big) cakes
I like (xx big xx) cakes
I like [big] cakes
I like [xx big xx] cakes
I like `big` cakes
I like `xx big xx` cakes
I like (xx(test(big test big ( big ))) big xx) cakes
```

Comment: What is the regex flavor? In .NET, for example, `(?<!\((?=[^()\n]*\))[^()\n]*)big` will work (`\n` only required in multiline mode). In PCRE, `\([^()\n]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|big` will work (`\n` is again necessary only for line only modes).

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET regex allows variable-width lookbehind patterns you can use

```
(?<!\((?=[^()\n]*\))[^()\n]*)big
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dc2XBY/1).

Note the `\n`s are only necessary when you need to match on a per-line basis. Remove all `\n`s when you need the pattern to work with standalone texts.

*Details*:

- `(?<!\((?=[^()\n]*\))[^()\n]*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `(` char and then zero or more chars other than parentheses and a newline immediately on the left, that is not immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than parentheses and a newline and then a `)` char
- `big` - `big` char sequence.

Comment: Damn. I found a combination that doesn't work after all.  Regex: ```(?<![\(\[`](?=[^()\n]*[\)\]`])[^()\n]*)big``` Should Match ```I like `xx` big `xx` cakes```  ==> https://regex101.com/r/Clffju/1

Comment: @TheBigNeo  Lookarounds won't help at all if your delimiters are identical chars, here, backticks. Yes, it is still possible to use a pattern like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/Clffju/3), but this won't be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take balanced parenthesis into account, you can use match those using [balancing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) and then use an alternation `|` and capture the word `\b(big)\b` in capture group 1.

```
\((?>\((?<open>)|[^\r\n()]+|\)(?<-open>))*(?(open)(?!))\)|\b(big)\b
```

See a [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sGKYiu/1).